# Relative layout not working programmatically added

Tags: android, android-layout

i have just started android programming, wrote a quick code, and havn't managed to get it to do what i want. Basically, i want a dialog box to appear, with 2 text boxes and an image shown in a particular layout. I have the following code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    RelativeLayout dialogItems = new RelativeLayout(this);
    EditText itemTitle = new EditText(this);
    EditText itemBody = new EditText(this);
    ImageView dIcon = new ImageView(this);

    itemTitle.setText("Note Title");
    itemBody.setText("Note Details");
    dIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.create);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    imageParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    dIcon.setLayoutParams(imageParam);
    dialogItems.addView(dIcon, imageParam);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams titleParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    titleParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, dIcon.getId());
    titleParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    itemTitle.setLayoutParams(titleParam);
    dialogItems.addView(itemTitle, titleParam);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bodyParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bodyParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, itemTitle.getId());
    bodyParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, itemTitle.getId());
    itemBody.setLayoutParams(bodyParam);
    dialogItems.addView(itemBody, bodyParam);

    dialog.setView(dialogItems);

    dialog.show();
```

Does anyone know why this wouldn't be working? The problem is, the popup appears, but all the items are just overlapping in the top left. Thanks

P.S. i have checked other posts and questions, and even the answers don't work! So please just fix my code rather than linking me to another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set the IDs so every view has the same ID (-1). This should work:

```
private static final int DIALOG_ITEMS_ID = 1;
private static final int ITEM_TITLE_ID = 2;
private static final int ITEM_BODY_ID = 3;
private static final int ICON_ID = 4;

RelativeLayout dialogItems = new RelativeLayout(this);
dialogItems.setId(DIALOG_ITEMS_ID);
EditText itemTitle = new EditText(this);
itemTitle.setId(ITEM_TITLE_ID);
EditText itemBody = new EditText(this);
itemBody.setId(ITEM_BODY_ID);
ImageView dIcon = new ImageView(this);
dIcon.setId(ICON_ID);
```

Comment: thanks i assumed that it would give the items their own id automatically... :P